Number of real solutions of $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$, where $f(x)=\frac{-x^{3}+15}{7}$

If $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{-x^3+15}{7}$ and $m$ be the number of real roots of $\displaystyle f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ and $n$ be the number of real roots of $f(x)=x$. Then $|m-n|$ is

What I try : First I calculate $n$:
$\displaystyle f(x)=x\Longrightarrow -x^3+15=7x$
$\displaystyle x^3+7x-15=0$
Only one real roots exists because $x^3+3x-15$ is increasing function.
But I did not how can I find inverse of cubic function.
Or any other way to solve
$\displaystyle f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$
Please help me to solve that problem.

This question is similar to: Problem on $f(x) =(-x^3 +15)/7,$ number of sol. of $f(x) =f^{-1}(x) =?$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@AmrutAyan I disagree because, as I indicate in my answer below, the only answer given in the linked duplicate uses computer-algebra-assistance.

@user2661923 yeah alright I retract my vote, I’ll leave that link as a reference for the OP

I've voted to close the other question as a duplicate of this one due to the quality of the answer.

In my opinion, the answer given in the linked duplicate can reasonably be construed as out of bounds, because it relies on computer assistance to identify the number of real roots.  That is, there are two possible interpretations of the posted question:

The problem solver is supposed to identify the exact number of (distinct) real roots by purely analytical methods.

The problem solver is merely supposed to (correctly) derive the inverse function $~f^{-1}(x),~$ and then is supposed to use computer-algebra-assistance to derive the exact number of distinct real roots.


Labeling the posted question as a duplicate to the linked question assumes that the 2nd bullet-point above represents the correct interpretation of the problem.  Absent any discussion by the OP (i.e. original poster) of computer-algebra-assistance, this does not seem like a reasonable interpretation of the problem.
Consequently, I subscribe to the interpretation in the 1st bullet-point above.  Given that, as discussed below, I construe the entire question as an unfair question, because I see no purely analytical solution to the problem.
The following analysis begins in a manner similar to the answer in the linked duplicate.

$$y = \frac{-x^3 + 15}{7} \implies (7y - 15) = -x^3 \implies \sqrt[3]{15 - 7y} = x.$$
Therefore,
$$f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt[3]{15 - 7x} \implies $$
$$f(x) - f^{-1}(x) = \frac{-x^3 + 15}{7} - \sqrt[3]{15 - 7x}.$$
Then
$$f(x) - f^{-1}(x) = 0 \iff $$
$$\frac{-x^3 + 15}{7} = \sqrt[3]{15 - 7x} \iff $$
$$\left[ ~\frac{-x^3 + 15}{7} ~\right]^3 = (15 - 7x) \iff $$
$$(-x^3 + 15)^3 = 7^3 ~(15 - 7x) = (-7^4)x + (7^3 \times 15) \iff $$
$$-x^9 + (3 \times 15) x^6 - (3 \times 225) x^3 + (15)^3 = (-7^4)x + (7^3 \times 15) \iff $$
$$-x^9(1) + x^6(3 \times 15) - x^3(3 \times 225) + x(7^4) - 15(7^3 - 15^2) = 0. \tag1 $$

To the best of my knowledge, the only reasonable way of analyzing the (possible) number of real roots of the equation in (1) above is by Descartes' Rule of Signs.
Using that rule, the number of (not necessarily distinct) positive (real) roots must be some element in $~\{0,2,4\},~$ and the number of negative (real) roots must be exactly $~1.$
The coefficients of the equation in (1) above seem far too large to expect the problem solver to (for example) guess and check that $~x=1~$ is a root of the polynomial.

The ninth degree polynomial can be factored as $$ -\frac{1}{4}(x-1)(x-2)\left[(2x^2+3x+5)+\sqrt{29}(x+3)\right]\left(2x^2+3x+5)-\sqrt{29}(x+3)\right$$ so there are 5 or 7 real root, depending on the third degree factor. This factor has only one real root, given that its derivative has constant sign.
